# Understanding the truthiness of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, truthiness

I understand that Python built-in types have a "truthiness" value, and the empty string is considered `False`, while any non-empty string is considered `True`.

#### This makes sense

I can check this using the built-in function `bool`.

```
>>> bool("")
False

>>> bool("dog")
True
```

I can also make use of these truthiness values when using conditionals. For example:

```
>>> if "dog":
...     print("yes")
...
yes
```

#### This is confusing

This doesn't work with the `==` operator though:

```
>>> "dog" == True
False

>>> "dog" == False
False
```

Can anyone explain why `==` seems to act differently than a conditional?

Comment: have you read the documentation?

Comment: `==` is comparison operator. a string and a boolean can never be equal.

Comment: When you compare `"dog" == "True"`, you are also comparing the type of these objects and not just their bool value.

Comment: here type is compared, not the value

Comment: I have pants. I am not equal to my pants. A string has a truth value. A string is not equal to its truth value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) and [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) sections of the documentation, excerpted below.

In a nutshell, most things are truthy by default, which is why `bool("dog")` is true.  The `==` operator compares two objects for equality, as opposed to comparing their truthinesses, as I assume you had expected.

> **4.1. Truth Value Testing**
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.
>
> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines
>   either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method
>   that returns zero, when called with the object.
>
> Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: `None` and `False`
> - zero of any numeric type: `0`, `0.0`, `0j`, `Decimal(0)`, `Fraction(0, 1)`
> - empty sequences and collections: `''`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `set()`, `range(0)`
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always 
>   return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise
>   stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations `or` and `and`
>   always return one of their operands.)
>
> **4.3. Comparisons**
>
> Objects of different types, except different numeric types, never
>   compare equal.
>
> ...
>
> Non-identical instances of a class normally compare as non-equal
>   unless the class defines the `__eq__()` method.

Answer (score 1):

#### The basics

I believe your confusion might come from comparing Python to languages such as JavaScript where there is a `==` and a `===` operator. Python does not work this way.

In Python the only way to compare for equality is with `==` and this compares both value and type.

Thus if you compare `True == "dog"`, then the expression is immediately `False` because the types `bool` and `str` are not types that can be compared.

Although, note that it does not mean that there are no types that are comparable between themselves. Examples are `set` and `frozenset`:

```
frozenset({1,2,3}) == {1,2,3} # True
```

Or simply `int` and `float`

```
1 == 1.0 # True
```

This is the behaviour for most built-in types.

#### The classy part

In the case where you *define your own types*, i.e. when you define classes, you can write the `__eq__` which is called when you compare a class object to another value.

By example you could do this (which by the way was pointed out as a terrible idea in the comments, you should not inherit built-in types).

```
class WeirdString(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return str(self) == str(other) or bool(self) == bool(other)

s = WeirdString("dog")
s == True # True
```

In the case where you do not define `__eq__`, then Python fall back on comparing whether the objects are *the same object* with `is`.

Comment: For those who wonder why I say *for most built-in types*, I was thinking of shady stuff like this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.__eq__

Comment: To be clear, `WeirdString` is a *terrible* idea. `s` in this case will be equal to `"foo"`, `{1}`, `[1]`, `-200.5`, `{'a': 1}`, `object()`, etc. Python is strongly typed for a reason; with dynamic typing already in play, weak typing makes it nigh impossible to write code you can reason about usefully. The real lesson here is to write idiomatic code, which *never* uses `== True` or `== False`, and just use implicit truthiness.

Comment: It is a terrible idea, I will mention this to be clear.

Comment: Also, standard `==` is not testing type explicitly. Different numeric types are comparable, `set` can be compared to `frozenset`, many bytes-like types compare to each other as expected, etc. Don't bring in the explicit type checking of JS's `===` here, it just confuses the matter.

Comment: I reworked my answer to include your remarks, that are on point by the way.

Answer (score 0):

> *When you compare `"dog" == True`, you are also comparing the type of these objects and not just their boolean value.*

Now as `True` has a type `bool` and `"dog"` has a type `str`, they are not equivalent according to the `==` operator, irrespective of their boolean values being equal.

**Note: Both the object's type,boolean values are being checked here.**

Comment: `True` inside a double quotes in not bool

Comment: @bro-grammer , Thanks i fixed it!